# How can I add atribute to webpage in django

Tags: django

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99y8b.png)I'm following a tutorial to create a website using django. I keep getting this error when running the server.
path('page2',index.webpage2),
AttributeError: module 'website.index' has no attribute 'webpage2'. Did you mean: 'webpage1'?

Don't know what I'm missing, the tutorial ran the server without any problem. The only thing I noticed was that it also gave my a missing os error. I fixed this part.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can You show code in views.py and urls.py file

Comment: I don't have views file. I trying to create one but a tutorial wants me to create a file and add some code that I already have on Index.py. you can see urls.py on the screenshot link on my question.thank you for your help.

Comment: can you show your index.py file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two views correspoending to the url

```
def webpage2(request):
   pass

def webpage3(request):
   pass
```